# How do I find additional subgraphs outside of the ones given by FindCycle?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm having trouble figuring out how to search and list additional subgraphs in my adjacency graphs outside of using `FindCycle`.  I have the following lines of code:

```
m = 8;
n = 8;
m1 = SparseArray[_ :> RandomInteger[1], {m, n}];
A = UpperTriangularize[m1] + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[m1, 1]];
AA = MatrixForm[A, 
  TableHeadings -> {{"A1", "A2", "A3",
      "A4", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
     "T4"},{"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", 
     "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"}}]

vertL = {"A", "A2", "A3", "A4", "T1",
    "T2", "T3", "T4"};
eColor = {
   {"A", "A"} -> Blue,
   {"T", "T"} -> Red
   };
va = StringTake[#, 1] &;
aga = AdjacencyGraph[vertL, A,
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
  VertexSize -> .5,
  VertexStyle -> White,
  EdgeStyle ->
   {Thick, UndirectedEdge[x_, y_] :> Replace[Sort@
       {va[x],
        va[y]},
      eColor]}
  ]
```

The code generates a random symmetric matrix "A" with elements of 0 and 1.  "aga" is the accompanying adjacency graph for matrix "A."  I then used

```
FindCycle[aga, {3}, All];
Map[VertexList, FindCycle[aga, {3}, All]]
```

The first line `FindCycle` finds all the complete subgraphs in "aga" of size 3.  The output gives me the list of vertices and the edges between them to give me a complete triangular subgraph 
(i.e. `{{A1-A2,A2-T3,T3-A1}...)`.  The second line `Map` gets rid of the edges to just give me the vertices which make up the subgraphs (i.e. `{{A1,A2,T3}...}`).

What I'm trying to do now is I want to list subgraphs in which there is a self loop to a "T" and that T is then connected to an "A"(It doesn't matter if the A has a self loop or not).  I've attached a picture below to help explain the issue.

In the sample graph provided, I can find all the complete subgraph cycles of 3, by performing the line of codes I've specified above.  What I want to do is also list subgraphs of the above criteria.  An example here is "T2" has a self loop to itself, it has an edge to "A4" and to "A1".  Those would give me subgraphs of `{T2,T2,A4}` and `{T2,T2,A1}`.  I want to then add those subgraphs to the list given by the `Map` function.

I'm looking for a generalized way to perform this function.  The adjacency graphs I'm working with are more complex than the one shown here where there could be multiple "T" vertices with self loops that are connect to an "A" vertice.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can take the `Diagonal` of the matrix, look for `1`s (self-loops), e.g. with `Position`, check which ones are `T`s, then apply `AdjacencyList` to each and see if any neighbours are `A`s.